# Disabling tilt effect for some items in ListView on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app showing a list of items in a `ListView`. I set 
`IsItemClickEnabled` to `True`.

There are two types of items in the `ListView`, "active" and "disabled" ones. Both type render differently, I use a `ItemTemplateSelector` to choose the right template.

I want the "active" items to be clickable with the standard tilt effect (pressed animation) and the "disabled" items not to generate the tilt effect (I do not care about the click being fired, I can handle that).

I found out I can disable the tilt effect on a `ListView` as a whole editing the `ItemContainerStyle` template. But how can I disable it only for some items in the `ListView`?

Comment: I used MS Blend to export template and see what's inside in cases like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable tilt in ItemContainerStyle, and enable tilt for individual item template...  by e.g. custom control with tilt effect.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions is to use a `ItemContainerStyleSelector`:

- define a custom `StyleSelector` with two style and the logic to switch between those two style
- use it as a `ItemContainerStyleSelector` on the `ListView`
- make sure you remove any explicit `ItemContainerStyle` from the `ListView`. If you define one, it will be taken as superior style, not a default style and the `StyleSelector` will not work.